# Limit woocommerce orders by IP

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to prevent selling more than 30 items per day by IP address in woocommerce. Basically, it is protection from bots.
I think logic must be something like this:

- get IP of a customer on a purchase and store it in the order meta
- check if there are other purchases from that IP at the past 24hr
- if more then 30 - display an error before payment and ask to return later

*user registration is disabled

So I'm not sure where to start and how to follow to woocommerce hooks rules.

Any code examples would be highly appreciated

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WooCommerce actually stores client IP addresses in the order metadata by default. You can use the `get_customer_ip_address()` method on a `WC_Order` to access this metadata. Likewise, WooCommerce includes `WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address()` to get the IP of the currently connected client.

Putting these together, you can use the `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook to give an error if a user with the same IP tries to make too many purchases in the given time period.

Here I'm using [`wc_get_orders()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) to succinctly query for all orders with a matching IP in the last 24 hours, and cancel the transaction if there are more than 30 results.

```
function my_ip_checker() {
    $last_24_hours_from_ip_results = wc_get_orders(array(
        'date_created'        => '>=' . (time() - 86400), // time in seconds
        'customer_ip_address' => WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address(),
        'paginate'            => true  // adds a total field to the results
    ));
    if($last_24_hours_from_ip_results->total > 30) { 
        wc_add_notice('Too many orders in the last 24 hours. Please return later.', 'error');
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_ip_checker', 10, 0);
```

Note that the call to `wc_add_notice()` with a type of `'error'` will stop the transaction from going through.

Comment: It works with some minor syntax fixes. Thanks a lot! Sorry I can`t vote you up

Comment: Oh good! Re: the syntax errors, by all means, edit my post and correct it! :)

Comment: Edited. Now it should work fine as long as server gives you the correct IP. 
(I`m using CloudFlare so correct IP is
$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])

Comment: it works fine for IP address, how i can use same for email address. i use as 
    'billing_email' => WC_Order::get_billing_email(),      but no luck? can you tell me what can i use?

Comment: So useful and succinct! Thank you S3cur3!

Comment: Where do you implement this code? The main WordPress functions.php file?

Comment: @JaydenLawson that'll work! :)