# Limit orders to a certain amount of products from a custom taxonomy (every 24 hours, by IP address)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to have it so that my customers are limited to order **5 products from a custom taxonomy every 24 hours** on my Woocommerce Wordpress site.

I have created a custom taxonomy called "product_theme" where products are either

- 'free'
- 'premium'

The "free" taxonomy is what I want to limit.

---

I have found and adjusted this code (found at [Limit woocommerce orders by IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852696/limit-woocommerce-orders-by-ip)) to my needs, and it currently does work to an extent.

However if I complete an order that is *not* in the 'free' term, the limits for my IP are essentially reset and I can then download an unlimited amount of free downloads. Perhaps the code only works on the latest order by that IP?

I think it may have something to do with the fact there are 2 'if' statements in there. I need it to be A. If the order contains a product in the 'free' attribute and B. If the IP address for the customer has created more than 2 order in the last 24 hours.

Here is what I have currently...

```php
function my_ip_checker() {

    $last_24_hours_from_ip_results = wc_get_orders(array(
        'date_created'        => '>=' . (time() - 86400), // time in seconds
        'customer_ip_address' => WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address(),
        'paginate'            => true  // adds a total field to the results
    ));

    if ( has_term( 'free', 'product_theme' ) ) { 
        if($last_24_hours_from_ip_results->total > 2) { 

            wc_add_notice('Daily limit exceeded for free downloads. Please come back in 24 hours.', 'error');
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_ip_checker', 10, 0);
```

EDIT: Trying to add it so that if the cart total is < 1, it shows error but if it is above 1, user can checkout successfully. Doesn't work though as user can checkout always.

```
function my_ip_checker() {
    $last_24_hours_from_ip_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'date_created'        => '>=' . (time() - 86400), // time in seconds
        'customer_ip_address' => WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address(),
    ));

    //set cart total
    $total = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    // Set variable
    $counter = 0;

    // Loop trough orders
    foreach ($last_24_hours_from_ip_orders as $last_24_hours_from_ip_order ) {
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $last_24_hours_from_ip_order );

        // Loop trough items
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Product id
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];

            // Has term (a certain category in this case)
            if ( has_term( 'free', 'product_theme', $product_id ) ) {
                $counter++;
            }
       }
    }

    if ( $counter >= 5 && sizeof($total) < 1 ) {

         wc_add_notice( __( 'Daily limit exceeded for free downloads. Please come back in 24 hours.' . $counter, 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_ip_checker', 10, 0 );
```

UPDATE: So the above code didn't work so I have added an additional 'if' within the 'if, has_term' statement and it's working. I also removed the $total variable entirely. So now, with the below code the customer can't checkout if they have A. downloaded more than 5 products from the custom taxonomy in the last 24 hours and B. If their cart total is 0. If cart total is above 0, they can checkout successfully.

```
function my_ip_checker() {
    $last_24_hours_from_ip_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'date_created'        => '>=' . (time() - 86400), // time in seconds
        'customer_ip_address' => WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address(),
    ));


    // Set variable
    $counter = 0;

    // Loop trough orders
    foreach ($last_24_hours_from_ip_orders as $last_24_hours_from_ip_order ) {
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $last_24_hours_from_ip_order );

        // Loop trough items
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Product id
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];

            // Has term (a certain category in this case)
            if ( has_term( 'free', 'product_theme', $product_id ) ) {

            if ( WC()->cart->total == '0' )   {
             $counter++;
            }

         }
       }
    }

    if ( $counter >= 5 ) {

         wc_add_notice( __( 'Daily limit exceeded for free downloads. Please come back in 24 hours.' . $counter, 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_ip_checker', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: in your question title it says "_Limit users to 2 Custom taxonomy orders per 24 hours in Woocommerce (by IP address)_". 
At the beginning of your question  "_limited to 5 FREE products every 24 hours_". 
Maybe you need to adjust and clarify your question accordingly?

Comment: I am limiting free products by adding every free product to the taxonomy 'free' in my custom taxonomy 'product_theme'. Maybe I wasn't clear enough with that.

Comment: Edited the question accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted counts the number of orders made in the last 24 hours from a specific ip address. Not the number of products in an order.

So i made some adjustments

> p.s. I don't use a custom taxonomy, so my code is based on a particular category. This is easily adjustable

```php
function my_ip_checker() {
    $last_24_hours_from_ip_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'date_created'        => '>=' . (time() - 86400), // time in seconds
        'customer_ip_address' => WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address(),
    ));

    // Set variable
    $counter = 0;

    // Loop trough orders
    foreach ($last_24_hours_from_ip_orders as $last_24_hours_from_ip_order ) {
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $last_24_hours_from_ip_order );

        // Loop trough items
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Product id
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];

            // Has term (a certain category in this case)
            if ( has_term( 'categorie-1', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                $counter++;
            }
       }
    }

    if ( $counter >= 5 ) {
         wc_add_notice( __( 'My error: ' . $counter, 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_ip_checker', 10, 0 );
```