# Avoid more than one purchase from the same IP

Tags: woocommerce

Good afternoon from Spain, guys.

I will try to be as specific as possible.

I want to create a free physical product in my ecommerce (WP + WC) for which I will only charge a couple of dollars for shipping.

To avoid cheating, apart from checking fields such as email and selling the product individually, I was wondering if it is possible to display a notice such as "IT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO MAKE MORE THAN ONE PURCHASE WITH THE SAME IP"

Any ideas?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Excuse me, you are right. Maybe I have not been as specific as I should.

I would like the message to appear on the product page just below the ADD TO CART button when the customer clicks it (and this is they have done so)

I hope I have clarified the question.

Thank you very much for your prompt reply.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this code out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859074/12415069) to restrict same-IP purchases.

---

That said - if your aim is to restrict purchases to one user, your best bet is to validate the user themselves (`email`/`username`).

The reason for this is:

- It's possible for one user to unintentionally access a page through many IPs (say VPN disconnects)
- It's possible for many users to use the same IP (via NAT).

IP should not be used for validation such as this.
And if you're already using emails, that should be good enough.

Comment: Users access my website as guests, so I will have to manually validate them for now.
Greetings and thank you